# PHPSpreadsheet isn't doing all the calculations after editing some cell values

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

Using PHPSpreadsheet I am editing an existing spreadsheet. The sheet contains 7 cells that I change the value of. After that I save the spreadsheet to a separate file.

However, after opening the file, all the values are changed to the expected values, but the cells where a calculation should be done isn't correct. The number is too high.

This is my code:

```
<?php

function get_calculation_annuiteit_with_user_input()
{
    $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
    if (!$user_input) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    $reader             = new Reader();
    $spreadsheet        = $reader->load(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../assets/sheet-annuiteit.xlsx');
    $user_input_decoded = json_decode(stripslashes($user_input), true);

    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'D11', $user_input_decoded['loan-amount-text']);
    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'D12', $user_input_decoded['calculate-annuity-per-select']);
    $interest_rate = validateAndSanitize($user_input_decoded['interest-amount-text']);
    $spreadsheet->getSheet(1)->getStyle('D13')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);
    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'D13', $interest_rate);
    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'E13', $user_input_decoded['interest-type-select']);
    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'D14', (int) $user_input_decoded['term-payment-duration-number']);
    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'E14', $user_input_decoded['term-payment-period-select']);
    setCellValue($spreadsheet, 'D15', $user_input_decoded['payment-moment-select']);

    $activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(1);
    $cellRanges  = ['D11', 'D14', 'G26'];
    foreach ($cellRanges as $cell) {
        $spreadsheet->getSheet(1)->getStyle($cell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');
    }

    $cellRangesPerGroup = [
        'E20:E22', 'F21:F22', 'G26:G26', 'H26:H26', 'I26:I26',
    ];

    $data = [];
    foreach ($cellRangesPerGroup as $group) {
        array_push($data, $activeSheet->rangeToArray($group, null, true, true, true));
    }

    Calculation::getInstance($spreadsheet)->clearCalculationCache();

    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'foobar.xlsx');

    $formatted_data = format_annuiteit_data($data);

    wp_send_json($formatted_data);
    wp_die();
}
```

I tried clearing the Calculation Engine and check if all cells are formatted the same as before.

Comment: I guess the calculated cells are not recalculated when you open the doc and keep their initial values (which are cached).

Comment: And how can I fix this? I am clearing the calculation cache on [line 39](https://gist.github.com/tislars/e55f10cdd8175b98227e11560cc46452#file-calculate_sheet-php-L39).

Comment: Does the cell keep the cached value, or is it recalculated to a wrong value?

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for your time. The cell is recalculated to a wrong value.

Comment: What functions do you use in your calculations? PHPSpreadSheet calculates the results in its own calculation engine, and there are some limitations with not all Excel functions being supported. You might also need to add extra brackets to explicitly set the calculation order.